# Personalization Rules Chaining

Tags: personalization, rules-engine

I need to use sitecore rules to personalize the contents that I want to display to users.

[image]

For example, I configured two basic rules on a component.
When used separately, both rules evaluate to true.

Is it possible to have rule chaining that is to execute rule 2 even if rule 1 returns true?

Answer (score 2):

You do this by chaining conditions.

Basically you can keep adding rule conditions to your expression, and combine them using AND and OR logic.

As below:

[image]

Comment: What i want to achieve is for both rules to execute. That is, if rule 1 returns true, perform action 1 and continue to executed rule 2.

Comment: Then you need to set up a combination of conditions as above. But there can only ever BE one action in this particular interface; which is "assign Data source".

Comment: Since the only action that can be performed is assigning a data source, I will be configuring different renderings with only one rule containing combination of conditions.